# Encrypt/Hide a value of a custom settings field

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I Encrypt/Hide a value of a custom settings field (token for instance), so it won't be readable when sending a request on network devtools ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to hit the API from the front-end? If yes try to do the callout from the back-end.

Comment: You can't. If you need encryption, `Custom Settings` are not sophisticated enough for your use case, and you may instead need `Custom Object`.

Comment: see this [document for options and best practices](https://security.secure.force.com/resource/DFSlides1/Storing_Secrets.pdf)